# Efficient generation of sampled waveforms without aliasing artifacts

Tags: audio, signal-processing, sampling, waveform

For a project of mine I am working with sampled sound generation and I need to create various waveforms at various frequencies. When the waveform is sinusoidal, everything is fine, but when the waveform is rectangular, there is trouble: it sounds as if it came from the eighties, and as the frequency increases, the notes sound wrong. On the 8th octave, each note sounds like a random note from some lower octave.

The undesirable effect is the same regardless of whether I use either one of the following two approaches:

- The purely mathematical way of generating a rectangular waveform as `sample = sign( secondsPerHalfWave - (timeSeconds % secondsPerWave) )` where `secondsPerWave = 1.0 / wavesPerSecond` and `secondsPerHalfWave = secondsPerWave / 2.0`
- My preferred way, which is to describe one period of the wave using line segments and to interpolate along these lines.  So, a rectangular waveform is described (regardless of sampling rate and regardless of frequency) by a horizontal line from x=0 to x=0.5 at y=1.0, followed by another horizontal line from x=0.5 to x=1.0 at y=-1.0.

From what I gather, the literature considers these waveform generation approaches "naive", resulting in "aliasing", which is the cause of all the undesirable effects.

What this all practically translates to when I look at the generated waveform is that the samples-per-second value is not an exact multiple of the waves-per-second value, so each wave does not have an even number of samples, which in turn means that the number of samples at level 1.0 is often not equal to the number of samples at level -1.0.

I found a certain solution here: https://www.nayuki.io/page/band-limited-square-waves which even includes source code in Java, and it does indeed sound awesome: all undesirable effects are gone, and each note sounds pure and at the right frequency. However, this solution is entirely unsuitable for me, because it is extremely computationally expensive. (Even after I have replaced `sin()` and `cos()` with approximations that are ten times faster than Java's built-in functions.) Besides, when I look at the resulting waveforms they look awfully complex, so I wonder whether they can legitimately be called rectangular.

### So, my question is:

What is the most ***computationally efficient*** method for the generation of periodic waveforms such as the rectangular waveform that does not suffer from aliasing artifacts?

#### Examples of what the solution could entail:

1. The computer audio problem of generating correct sample values at discrete time intervals to describe a sound wave seems to me somewhat related to the computer graphics problem of generating correct integer y coordinates at discrete integer x coordinates for drawing lines. The Bresenham line generation algorithm is extremely efficient, (even if we disregard for a moment the fact that it is working with integer math,) and it works by accumulating a certain error term which, at the right time, results in a bump in the Y coordinate. Could some similar mechanism perhaps be used for calculating sample values?
2. The way sampling works is understood to be as reading the value of the analog signal at a specific, infinitely narrow point in time. Perhaps a better approach would be to consider reading the area of the entire slice of the analog signal between the last sample and the current sample. This way, sampling a 1.0 right before the edge of the rectangular waveform would contribute a little to the sample value, while sampling a -1.0 considerable time after the edge would contribute a lot, thus naturally yielding a point which is between the two extreme values. Would this solve the problem? Does such an algorithm exist? Has anyone ever tried it?

Please note that I have posted this question here as opposed to dsp.stackexchange.com because I do not want to receive answers with preposterous jargon like band-limiting, harmonics and low-pass filters, lagrange interpolations, DC compensations, etc. and I do not want answers that come from the purely analog world or the purely theoretical outer space and have no chance of ever receiving a practical and efficient implementation using a digital computer.

I am a programmer, not a sound engineer, and in my little programmer's world, things are simple: I have an array of samples which must all be between -1.0 and 1.0, and will be played at a certain rate (44100 samples per second.) I have arithmetic operations and trigonometric functions at my disposal, I can describe lines and use simple linear interpolation, and I need to generate the samples extremely efficiently because the generation of a dozen waveforms simultaneously and also the mixing of them together may not consume more than 1% of the total CPU time.

***AMENDMENT***

For anyone wondering what happened with this, read this post on my blog:

[michael.gr - Digital Audio Waveform Generation](https://blog.michael.gr/2022/03/digital-audio-waveform-generation.html)

Comment: Since this is a DSP question I was about to recommend https://dsp.stackexchange.com until I read your reasons to avoid it. I would still suggest that be your first port of call. It is a shame that the community appears to have a negative reputation for jargon, but nevertheless, if you don't ask you don't get. One key term you are missing here is [_nyquist frequency_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), that is the source of the artefacts you are getting.

Comment: This is going to sound like equally unhelpful jargon, but one particular algorithm you may want to look at is _PolyBLEP_ .Have a read of [**Antialiasing Oscillators in Subtractive Synthesis** _Published in: IEEE Signal Processing Magazine ( Volume: 24, Issue: 2, March 2007)_](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4117934?casa_token=tbLyqzTQiQMAAAAA:beJiY1lmePb8wotluILgs224rkZMzD65fEWs3robfxUCFua8ib8VbO3KCVIPImqufl4QCL-6cA). I can have a look at digesting it into an answer, though you may want to add a language tag to your question in that case.

Comment: I'd recommend the JUCE forum as well for musical implementations of DSP https://forum.juce.com

Comment: @fdcpp I will consider posting at dsp after I see what answers I can get here. As for the nyquist frequency, well, it is just half the sampling rate, and my sampling rate is fixed, so I have no control over it. My observation that the problem is most noticeable in the higher octaves is another way of saying that the closer I get to the nyquist frequency, the greater the distortion is, due to aliasing. But the distortion exists in all frequencies, (that '80s feel,) and a solution that would remove it from the high frequencies should also remove it from all frequencies.

Comment: Also thanks for the link to the IEEE article. Unfortunately, they want $33 to show it to me.   I intentionally avoided adding a language tag because I do not want to limit the audience of the question. I am comfortable with Java, C#, C++, C, Scala, even Pascal. I can also come to a stackoverflow chat channel if you want, or exchange e-mails, my address is michael at michael dot gr.  Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: Basically anything going _over_ the nyquist will mirror back that is what is causing the extra artefacts. Something like a perfect square wave is actually an infinite series, so by definition it would need t go over your nyquist. You can apply a filter to stop it, only sum a finite number of harmonics ([resulting in gibbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon)) or some jiggery pokery like PolyBLEP. Nyquist frequency aliasing should yield some more results for you. Apologies about the article link, I forget not everyone messing with this stuff isn't academia sometimes.

Comment: Not sure of the machinations of SO chat, that is a feature I wasn't aware of, but happy to exchange emails.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: @fdcpp Hey, thanks for responding.  Well, I found some implementation of PolyBLEP and I am giving it a try.  But it will take some time before I have some results, because I am working on it on my spare time.

Comment: @fdcpp but the initial results look very promising. It does not add a lot of computation, the  sample points along the waveforms look exactly right, and the waveforms sound exactly right.

Comment: @fdcpp I have some results now.  A second brain, a second pair of eyes, a second pair of ears would be very useful and very much appreciated at this point in time.  If you sent me an e-mail, I did not receive it.  If not, now is the time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but you may have a few of misconceptions about the nature of aliasing. I base this on your putting the term in quotes, and from the following quote:

> What this all practically translates to when I look at the generated
> waveform is that the samples-per-second value is not an exact multiple
> of the waves-per-second value, so each wave does not have an even
> number of samples, which in turn means that the number of samples at
> level 1.0 is often not equal to the number of samples at level -1.0.

The samples/sec and waves/sec don't have to be exact multiples at all! One can play back all pitches below the Nyquist. So I'm not clear what your thinking on this is.

The characteristic sound of a square wave arises from the presence of odd harmonics, e.g., with a note of 440 (A5), the square wave sound could be generated by combining sines of 440, 1320, 2200, 3080, 3960, etc. progressing in increments of 880. This begs the question, how many odd harmonics? We could go to infinity, theoretically, for the sharpest possible corner on our square wave. If you simply "draw" this in the audio stream, the progression will continue well beyond the Nyquist number.

But there is a problem in that harmonics that are higher than the Nyquist value cannot be accurately reproduced digitally. Attempts to do so result in aliasing. So, to get as good a sounding square wave as the system is able to produce, one has to avoid the higher harmonics that are present in the theoretically perfect square wave.

I think the most common solution is to use a low-pass filtering algorithm. The computations are definitely more cpu-intensive than just calculating sine waves (or doing FM synthesis, which was my main interest). I am also weak on the math for DSP and concerned about cpu expense, and so, avoided this approach for long time. But it is quite viable and worth an additional look, imho.

Another approach is to use additive synthesis, and include as many sine harmonics as you need to get the tonal quality you want. The problem then is that the more harmonics you add, the more computation you are doing. Also, the top harmonics must be kept track of as they limit the highest note you can play. For example if using 10 harmonics, the note 500Hz would include content at 10500 Hz. That's below the Nyquist value for 44100 fps (which is 22050 Hz). But you'll only be able to go up about another octave (doubles everything) with a 10-harmonic wave and little more before your harmonic content goes over the limit and starts aliasing.

Instead of computing multiple sines on the fly, another solution you might consider is to instead create a set of lookup tables (LUTs) for your square wave. To create the values in the table, iterate through and add the values from the sine harmonics that will safely remain under the Nyquist for the range in which you use the given table. I think a table of something like 1024 values to encode a single period could be a good first guess as to what would work.

For example, I am guestimating, but the table for the octave C4-C5 might use 10 harmonics, the table for C5-C6 only 5, the table for C3-C4 might have 20. I can't recall what this strategy/technique is called, but I do recall it has a name, it is an accepted way of dealing with the situation. Depending on how the transitions sound and the amount of high-end content you want, you can use fewer or more LUTs.

There may be other methods to consider. The wikipedia entry on Aliasing describes a technique it refers to as "bandpass" that seems to be intentionally using aliasing. I don't know what that is about or how it relates to the article you cite.

Comment: When I wrote "the number of samples at level 1.0 is often not equal to the number of samples at level -1.0" I meant ***in a sequence of waves of the same frequency***.  This is the actual physical defect that causes the phenomenon called aliasing, and all anti-aliasing techniques try to mitigate exactly that, with various degrees of success, and at various computational costs.  You can stack as much theory and jargon as you wish on top of it, but this is what it all boils down to.

Comment: And I should have further qualified this, because it is a bit indirect. The actual problem is simply that the wave length is not exactly divisible by the number of samples.  The different numbers of samples at 1.0 and -1.0 (when generating the waveform using a naïve approach) are a result of this, and they are what an observer is likely to notice first when troubleshooting the waveform. The next thing that the observer is likely to notice is that the number of samples from peak to peak may be off by one, among waves of the same frequency.

Comment: That is an interesting contention, and I wonder if it is mathematically correct. It seems to me that aliasing can occur while we get the same number of positive and negative data values on a wave, and that a signal that does not have aliasing can be unbalanced. I'm using as plain language as I can. Are you able to follow the logic of what I cited, or are you dismissing it out-of-hand?

Comment: A wave of 440 Hz can be heard with a frame rate of 44100 fps, despite the ratio between them being 100.227272727. I'm not following your logic.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying; I am tempted to doubt that such a signal can exist, but I do not really know. But what I do know is that aliasing the way I described it perfectly matches the concept of aliasing in graphics: if you try to draw parallel lines 3.5 pixels apart, you get aliasing.

Comment: As for the 440 Hz signal, at 44100 sampling rate, it will need aliasing, or else it will sound bad.  And this is what this stackoverflow question is all about: how to anti-alias a signal efficiently.

Comment: (Or rather, how to efficiently generate an already anti-aliased signal. Because generating an aliased signal and then anti-aliasing it after the fact makes about as much sense as travelling from Boston to NYC via L.A.)

Comment: The term aliasing in the sphere of graphics is pretty distinct from the aliasing in audio. The term refers to the audio artifact, not the technique to allow the correct pitch to be heard. Intermediate values are permitted between -1 and 1, and linear interpolation is usually sufficient with floats.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Anti-aliasing is indeed the same concept in graphics and in audio. The difference is that in graphics you have to worry about the time domain (e.g. excessive ringing) and the frequency domain (e.g. limited-bandwidth analog TV signal) at the same time. Whereas in audio, you mainly care about the frequency domain, and ringing is basically inaudible.

Comment: IDK about that assessment. True, in both cases, the term is used in relationship to problems encountered when trying to encode and present a signal or content where the granularity of the encoding system creates distortions. But with visual anti-aliasing, I am used to that referring to a strategy of introducing variability to the signal, so that the signal repeatedly crosses a unit threshold, avoiding a stair-step effect. In audio, when a signal has a higher frequency than the Nyquist, the resulting encoded signal can be wildly off, and introducing variability does nothing to ameliorate this.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Thanks for the response, but I don't agree with what you said. I stand by my statement that visual antialiasing largely overlaps with audio antialiasing, and should not be treated that differently. I disagree with a number of terms and concepts you said, like "introducing variability", "avoid stair-step". You can email me if you want a longer discussion. I also urge you to watch Xiph.Org's demonstration video on antialiasing to see some of the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

The [Soundpipe](https://github.com/PaulBatchelor/Soundpipe) library has the concept of a frequency table, which is a data structure that holds a precomputed waveform such as a sine. You can initialize the frequency table with the desired waveform and play it through an [oscilator](https://pbat.ch/res/soundpipe/docs/osc.html). There is even a module named [oscmorph](https://pbat.ch/res/soundpipe/docs/oscmorph.html) which allows you to morph between two or more wavetables.

This is an example of how to generate a sine wave, taken from Soundpipe's [documentation](https://pbat.ch/proj/soundpipe.html).

```
int main() {
    UserData ud;
    sp_data *sp;
    sp_create(&sp);
    sp_ftbl_create(sp, &ud.ft, 2048);
    sp_osc_create(&ud.osc);

    sp_gen_sine(sp, ud.ft);
    sp_osc_init(sp, ud.osc, ud.ft);
    ud.osc->freq = 500;
    sp->len = 44100 * 5;
    sp_process(sp, &ud, write_osc);

    sp_ftbl_destroy(&ud.ft);
    sp_osc_destroy(&ud.osc);
    sp_destroy(&sp);
    return 0;
}
```