# Weird notes being played on piezo buzzer when deviding with not a constant integer

Tags: c, pic, mplab

So this is a more complicated problem. I am currently programming a little developer test board with a PIC16F1509 with the MPLAB X IDE and flashing the compiled hex file via a custom USB UART Bridge onto the board. My problem is following: The piezo is not connected to one of the PWM pins (has a reason). Since i am pretty new to C and Programming ICs i am currently hard coding almost everything. I wanted to create a melody today and it worked fine like this:

```
void NOTE_A4 (void) { 
    for (int i = 0; i <= 440; i++)
    {
    sound1_SetHigh();
    __delay_us(1136);
    sound1_SetLow();
    __delay_us(1136);
    }   
}
```

So if i call this function i would get one second of the note.

Since i wanted to be able to change the timings length of the notes i tried following:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 440/5; i++) {}
```

This would allow me to play for 200ms with no problems.

I also wanted to be able to change the length when i call the function so i did this:

```
void NOTE_A4 (int divider) { 
    for (int i = 0; i <= 440/divider; i++)
    {
    sound1_SetHigh();
    __delay_us(1136);
    sound1_SetLow();
    __delay_us(1136);
    }  
}
```

Now i have the problem that it just sounds weird.
[Recording of the song](https://linksharing.samsungcloud.com/wPyAXqxgT8uC)

I cant figure out why that happens since the for loop calculates the new number correctly.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try computing `440/divider` once ***before*** entering the loop, just to rule out the possibility that the particular combination of how smart your compiler is, together with the level of optimizations you have selected, causes the division to be repeated in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: In microprocssser work I would usually run a loop downwards where possible. This woild avoid the possibility of multiple computations of the end value, and the end condition doesn't need a specific comparison on most processors because the decrement sets the flags, so the decision can be made without needing a 'compare' instruction.

Comment: @WeatherVane even on a debug build with optimizations disabled, where you are supposed to be able to single-step through the loop and watch the loop counter incrementing?

Comment: @Lipe did you try the code with other hard-coded values to check its performance?

Comment: @MikeNakis: I watch the loop counter decrementing.

Comment: @Weather Vane. As long as i use hard coded values the sound sound good no matter what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is to compute `440/divider` once before entering the loop, just to rule out the possibility that the particular combination of how smart/dumb your compiler is, together with the level of optimizations you have selected, causes the division to be repeated in each iteration of the loop. But I doubt that this is the problem.

Your problem is probably ***aliasing***, and it is a very hard problem to solve. If aliasing is your problem, and you find a solution, please post it here. For more information about ***aliasing*** read this: [Stack Overflow - Efficient generation of sampled waveforms without aliasing artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66943566/efficient-generation-of-sampled-waveforms-without-aliasing-artifacts)

Comment: This kinda solved my problem. I am calculating the time now before the loop. Sadly you are still able to hear the millisecond in which the code calculates the new time. So its like a little up and down when the same note is playing more then one time

Comment: The original tune is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djV11Xbc914 assuming you transcribed the notes correctly, and assuming you have the correct frequency for each note, then no matter how bad quality your buzzer is, you definitely  ***also*** have an aliasing problem with your frequency generator.

Answer (score 0):

The [PIC16F1xxx Instruction Set](https://microchipdeveloper.com/mcu1102:instruction-set) does not have a divide instruction, and so the software implementation of division is likely to be very slow.

The loop timing is probably affected by the run time division `440/divider`, being implemented in software.

However the hard coded `440/5` is computed during compilation.

One way to get round this is with the use of precalculated look-up tables. A full sized piano has 77 keys: that isn't a very large lookup table.

Comment: Is there something in C like in C++ that calculates it on compiletime?

Comment: No, because you don't know the divisor's value until run time.

Comment: Oh, I do not. I am just asking the OP whether your answer did in fact turn out to be the correct answer. My question is to the OP.  I never placed a "strategic downvote" (ew, the euphemism) in my  10+ years on stackoverflow.

Comment: FYI, a full-sized piano has 88 keys, not 77.

Comment: @TimČas I must have been thinking of trombones.

Comment: @MikeNakis plainly the division was the problem, and not the aliasing.

Comment: @WeatherVane well, that's why I included both parts in my answer. The thing with aliasing is that its perception is subjective. He may also be getting aliasing, and he may not know it. I did not know what his problem was, because he only gave us an audio file showing how it sounds, not how he expected it to sound. I think I heard aliasing.

Comment: @MikeNakis good thinking, but it hasn't solved OP's problem, although you hi-jacked the answer acceptance. That really is bad form - let the OP and the community vote as they will. A look-up table may be what OP needs to get rid of the hesitation mentioned.

Comment: Seriously, you think that the OP changed the accepted answer because I asked him why he had accepted yours?

Comment: That was your intention, obviously. The whole thing is naff.

Comment: I dont care enough to have such an intention. I am in search of the truth, not votes.

Comment: Your answer was not the truth, although it contained a valid point. You posted an answer, and asked the OP why they accepted this one. I can't believe how you can do that. My answer was correct all along. The OP needs to get rid of the run-time division.